# Find the largest integer in an array

Tags: solidity

2. Write a function that:

   1. Is named `getMax`
   2. Takes in an array of `uint256`
   3. Returns the largest number in the array

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this site is not meant to code for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
    function getMax(uint256[] calldata numbers ) public pure returns(uint maxNumber) {

    uint arrayLength = numbers.length;
    uint maxNumber; // The largest number in array

    for(uint index = 0; index < arrayLength; )  {

       if(numbers[index] > maxNumber)
           maxNumber = numbers[index];

        unchecked{++index;}

    }

    return maxNumber;

}
```

Wrote it in 5sec. I didn't have time to test.(You said it's urgent)

This if the refined and better version.

```
    function getMax(uint256[] calldata numbers ) public pure returns(uint maxNumber) {

    uint arrayLength = numbers.length;

    for(uint index = 0; index < arrayLength; )  {

        if(numbers[index] > maxNumber)
            maxNumber = numbers[index];

        unchecked{index++;}
    }

}
```